# Minor change policy regarding real names

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, too-minor

When reviewing edits, I often find minor changes which simply remove the name from the original question. So the user wrote something like

```
Thanks,
    myname
```

at the end of the question and somebody edits this out.

OK, the greetings is not really necessary for a posting so it doesn't hurt. If I see that the original poster wants to remove it, it's also fine for me. However if somebody else removes this, without any other changes I'm a bit torn.

For privacy reasons I would personally agree, as I feel that the name of the person shouldn't matter, and it just makes tracking easier for cross referencing with other information about a given person in the internet. However, if the person added his name, then he should know what he is doing, so why should I disrespect that by removing his name?

So, should such a change be rejected as a minor edit, or should it be approved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name is not relevant to the question nor is the greeting.

It has been [established long ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) that parts of a post that are not relevant to it can and should be removed.

If a user finds it important enough to show their name, they should change it on their profile page - problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

The name of the OP is regardless the question the OP is asking.

That kind of greeting should be removed from the post. This kind of changes also be approved by the reviewer.

Also check the link provided by **Oded** [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)